# Is mean independence symmetric

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence

Consider two random variables X and Y

If X is mean independent of Y, is it necessarily true that Y is mean independent of X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No:  Consider the following four events with equal probabilities

```
 Y     X
+1    +2 
+1    -2
-1    +5
-1    -5
```

- $\mathbb E[X \mid Y=+1]= 0$ and $\mathbb E[X \mid Y=-1]= 0$
- $\mathbb E[Y \mid X=+2]= +1$ but $\mathbb E[Y \mid X=+5]= -1$